# How to configure webpack chunks for multiple entries

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

How to configure webpack chunks for multiple entries?

Entries:

1. `outer.js` - includes [vue.js, some outer components]
2. `inner.js` - includes [vue.js, flatpickr, some inner components]

Expected output:

`outer-chunk.js` - [vue.js]

`inner-chunk.js` - [flatpickr.js]

`outer.js` - [some outer components]

`inner.js` - [some inner components]

Comment: what webpack version you use?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I'm using vue-cli 4.5.0